# Defending against XSS attack with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a project in `node.js` which uses `mongoose` to handle `MongoDB`. I want to defend against XSS attacks. What is the suggested way to do it? I found this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-sanitizer

Could it work? I am looking for a solution which doesn't require checking every single input.

Comment: Do you mean NoSQL injection rather than XSS attacks?

Comment: "*I am looking for a solution which doesn't require checking every single input.*" - yes you should. Inputs are of different types, and you will need to check them according to their purpose. You will only need to use a sanitiser if you want to accept HTML input, which should be rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mongo-sanitize`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize) is your best bet for sanitizing all input. You can sanitize directly in Mongoose operations or, possibly better, sanitize immediately when input is received by the server.

```
var sanitize = require("mongo-sanitize");
MongooseModel.update({ value: sanitize(input) }, function(err, doc) {
    // ...
});
```

The type of attack you are trying to avoid is called a [NoSQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection).

Comment: Actually, `mongoose-sanitizer` doesn't have anything to do with preventing NoSQL injection; it's for sanitizing user-provided HTML strings.

Comment: You sanitize inputs so special characters are escaped before insertion. That is absolutely NoSQL injection prevention.

Comment: I know it's subtle, but it's actually different. From the link you included in your answer: `filtering out common HTML special characters such as < > & ; will not prevent attacks against a JSON API`

Comment: I understand the definition. I overlooked that mongoose-sanitizer only handles special _HTML_ characters and not special _JSON_ characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NPM packages like:

1. **xss** : (Sanitize untrusted HTML (to prevent XSS) with a configuration specified by a whitelist)
2. **express-mongo-sanitize** : Express middleware which sanitizes user-supplied data to prevent MongoDB Operator Injection.
3. **Helmet** : Sets security-related HTTP response headers to protect against some well-known web vulnerabilities.